# Invert image pixels after 1 inversion

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a piece of code, seen below, that I'm using to invert the pixel data of an image. This code works forward on the initial inversion (black becomes white, white becomes black, etc). However, when I take the inverted image file and rerun it through this code to try and get the original image, the values are nowhere near the original and the image has random dark patches and very high contrast.

So tell me, what is a better way to get the inversion of the inversion? Does the below code need tweaking? Is there another way to go about this entirely?

Code:

```
//bitsStored is the bit depth. In this test, it is 10.
//imageBytes is the pixel data in a byte array
public static short[] invert(int bitsStored) {
    short min = min(imageBytes);//custom method. Gets the minimum value in the byte array. 
    short range = (short) (2 << bitsStored);
    short[] holder = new short[imageBytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageBytes.length; i++) {
        holder[i] = (short) (range - imageBytes[i] - min);
    }
    imageBytes = holder;
    return imageBytes;
}
```

Note: The image I'm using has a 16-bit depth but only uses 10-bits for storage.

Let me know if there is any way I can make my question clearer. Thank you!

**EDIT**: I have an idea. Could this be happening because the min value changes between the first run and the second? I feel like, in concept, the inversion of an inversion should be the original. But in the math, the only number that is the same between the two runs is the range value. So there has to be a better way to do this. I'll continue to think about it, but any insights you guys have on it would be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, you would invert the color(if I got the invert right) by XOR the color with the minimum block value (let say `0xFFFFFFFF` in full 32-bit profile).

Comment: @user7859067 I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Could you explain with an example? Forgive me, I'm relatively new to image processing with java.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that holder[i]=imageBytes[i]^min is what I should use instead of what's there? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes, for invert a color, you need to `XOR` each color part (`R`, `G`, and `B`) with `0xFF`, or the whole color int value with `0xFFFFFFFF`. So it could be holder[i]=imageBytes[i]^`0xFFFFFFFF`. but as far as there is no Alpha, you may need to not XOR the alpha section.